# nth derivative of rational power

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I am looking for the proof of kth derivative $x^a$, where $a$ is rational, and $x>0$,(I do not need general form, because we haven't defined irrational powers yet) but all the proofs I have seen just considering integers
$$\frac{d^{k}}{d x^{k}} x^{a}=a(a-1) \ldots(a-k+1) x^{a-k}$$

Comment: It is less clear what $x^a$ means for arbitrary real numbers $x$ when $a$ is a rational number that is not an integer, than for integer exponents.  In particular the cases $x\lt 0$ are not well-defined values, but when $x \gt 0$ the usual rules of calculus hold (and the values are well-defined if we are defining the principal (real) result).

Comment: oh sorry  I forgot x>0

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}[x^a] = \frac{d}{dx}[e^{a\ln(x)}]=\frac{a}{x}e^{a\ln(x)}=\frac{a}{x}x^a=ax^{a-1}$

Comment: In that case you can prove the formula for repeated derivatives by induction on $k$ (once you prove it for the single differentiation rule).  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4001006/elementary-proof-of-power-rule-for-differentiation-fx-rxr-1-for-fx-x).

Comment: This is overkill, but if you already know that this derivative holds for integers, you can deduce the general case with the implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = x^{q}$, where $q$ is rational. Then one has that

\begin{align*}
f(x) = x^{q} & \Rightarrow \ln f(x) = q\ln(x)\\\\
& \Rightarrow \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{q}{x}\\\\
& \Rightarrow f'(x) = \frac{qf(x)}{x}\\\\
& \Rightarrow f'(x) = qx^{q-1}
\end{align*}

The same reasoning applies to real exponents.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks Sir I will try

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad I could help.

Comment: Can we continue with induction to prove nth derivative. is it right??

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m,n\in\Bbb Z\setminus \{0\}$ and $x, x+h>0$.

$$\frac{(x+h)^{m/n}-x^{m/n}}h=\frac{(x+h)^m-x^m}{h\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(x+h)^{mj/n}x^{m(n-j-1)/n}}=\frac{\frac{(x+h)^m-x^m}h}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(x+h)^{mj/n}x^{m(n-j-1)/n}}$$

Call $g(t)=t^m$. You have $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^{m/n}-x^{m/n}}h=\frac{g'(x)}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x^{mj/n}x^{m(n-j-1)/n}}=\frac{mx^{m-1}}{nx^{m(n-1)/n}}=\frac mnx^{\frac mn-1}$$

Once you know that $(x^q)'=qx^{q-1}$ for $q\in\Bbb Q$ as well, it's easy.