# Proving $\lim \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=n\cdot a^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

**Please note that this question was asked by one of my students who doesn't know differentiation yet nor Lhopital nor mean value theorems. We teach limits before all these topics like differentiation , MVT , Lhopital , etc**

$$\lim_{ x \to a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=n\cdot a^{n-1}$$

I can prove this result for $n \in \mathbb Z$

And for $n \in \mathbb Q $ , that is when $n =\frac{p}{q}$ , I can prove the result using the result for $n \in\mathbb Z$.

**But my question is this :**

Since $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$ , why can't we prove this result only for $n \in \mathbb Q$ ?

Is there a method to prove $$\lim_{ x \to a} \frac{x^\frac{p}{q}-a^\frac{p}{q}}{x-a}=\frac{p}{q}\cdot a^{\frac{p}{q}-1}$$ without the result for $n \in \mathbb Z $  ?

Comment: Lhopital easily seems to justify your claim.

Comment: @Avi  Without using Lhopital !

Comment: How can we prove any thing about anything to do with $x^{\frac pq}$ without appealing to the definition osf $x^{\frac pq} = \sqrt[q] x^p; p,q \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: General binomial theorem may be useful.

Comment: Or use mean value theorem for $f(x)=x^{\frac{p}{q}}$

Comment: "General binomial theorem may be useful"  what is the general binomial theorem on rational exponents?

Comment: Just take n= p/q. The result will follow from the general binomial theorem as n is non negative. ( just took gcy-rolle's hint half step further :))

Comment: You might want to refer to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem

Comment: @gcy-rolle, you are right about general binomial theorem, it leads to simple calculation of the limit, but it really is a Taylor expansion, and I doubt power series are studied before differentiation. Though, I guess OP could easily demonstrate calculation if the student would be willing to make "a leap of faith" that everything behaves just the same as in the case where $n$ is positive integer.

Answer (score 6):

I'll prove it for $a=1$, it generalises fairly nicely from there:

$$\frac{x^{p/q}-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x^{1/q})^p-1}{(x^{1/q})^q-1}=\frac{\frac{(x^{1/q})^p-1}{x^{1/q}-1}}{\frac{(x^{1/q})^q-1}{x^{1/q}-1}}=\frac{1+x^{1/q}+x^{2/q}+\cdots+x^{p-1/q}}{1+x^{1/q}+x^{2/q}+\cdots+x^{q-1/q}}\to\frac{p}{q} \text{ as }x\to1$$

Note that the third equals sign comes from $\frac{y^n-1}{y-1}=y^{n-1}+y^{n-2}+\cdots+y+1$.

Comment: "But my question is this : Is there a method to prove without the result for n∈Z ?"  You did not address this at all.

Comment: I haven't used the result for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ though - I've taken $n=p/q$, and used standard algebraic techniques from there.

Comment: You've converted $x^{p/q} = [x^{1/q}]^p$ and and relied on $p \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @fleablood Right - I'm not sure how that's a problem. I might be missing something - my understanding of OP's question was that they wanted a way of proving what the derivative of $x^n$ was for non-integer, rational $n$, which didn't rely on knowing what the derivative of $x^n$ was for integer $n$. [I know OP says we're not assuming knowledge of differentiation, but it's the simplest way of referring to the limits in question]

Comment: Hmmm, I intepretted the OPs comment differently.. namely that you prove it for $n \in Z$ and then apply $x^n = x^{p/q} = (x^{1/q})^p = y^{n'}$ with $n' \in Z$ and the OP (for reasons unknown) wanted a direct proof for rational $p/q$ without an intermediate integer step.

Comment: @fleablood I'm still a little confused - are you taking issue with expressing a rational number as a ratio of integers?

Comment: No.  We prove this result for n where n is an integer directly.  Then if r is rational we simply replace $z^r $ with $w^n $ where $r =n/m$ and $w = mth root (z)$ for integer n and m, and appeal to the result for integers.  The op distinctly said he does not want to do that.  He wants to prove it for rational numbers *without* first proving it for integers.  I don't know *why* the op wants to do that, but that was has question.  Your proof requires showing it for integers.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion:

"Since Z⊂Q , why can't we prove this result only for n∈Q

?"

Is there a method to prove
limx→a $x^{p/q}−a^{p/q}/x−a=p/q⋅a^{p/q−1}$
without the result for n∈Z ? "

I'd say "Not really".

We've only defined $x^{p/q}$ as ${\sqrt[q]{x}}^p$ and haven't really explored any ideas of what this can mean other than $x^r \approx y^n$ by "plugging in" $\sqrt[q]x$ for $y$ and $n = rq \in \mathbb Z$ for $n$.

So if we've only *defined* $x^r$ in terms of integers we can't do anything else.... yet.

Once we get some results about $x^r$ that don't rely on an integer definition we can.  Maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Proving $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^{\frac{p}{q}}-a^{\frac{p}{q}}}{x-a}={\frac{p}{q}}\cdot a^{{\frac{p}{q}}-1}\,(p,q\in{\mathbb{Z}})$$

First,let $$y=x^{\frac{p}{q}}-a^{\frac{p}{q}} $$

Then,we can know $$y+a^{\frac{p}{q}}=x^{\frac{p}{q}}$$
$$(y+a^{\frac{p}{q}})^q=x^p$$
Use Binomial theorem:
$$(y+a^{\frac{p}{q}})^q=y^q+q*y^{q-1}*a^{\frac{p}{q}}+...+q*y*a^\frac{p(q-1)}{q}+a^p$$
So,we can get:$$x^p-a^p=y^q+q*y^{q-1}*a^{\frac{p}{q}}+...+q*y*a^\frac{p(q-1)}{q}$$
For the identity: $$(x^p-a^p)=(x-a)(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}*a+...+x*a^{p-2}+a^{p-1})$$
So $$x-a=\frac{y^q+q*y^{q-1}*a^{\frac{p}{q}}+...+q*y*a^\frac{p(q-1)}{q}}{x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}*a+...+x*a^{p-2}+a^{p-1}}$$
Finally, $$\frac{y}{x-a}=\frac{x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}*a+...+x*a^{p-2}+a^{p-1}}{y^{q-1}+q*y^{q-2}*a^{\frac{p}{q}}+...+q*a^\frac{p(q-1)}{q}}$$
Obviously:$$\lim_{x\to a}y=0 \,\,\,and\,\,\, \lim_{y\to 0}c*y^k=0({c}\in{\mathbb{R}},{k}\in{\mathbb{N^{+}}})$$
At last:$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^{\frac{p}{q}}-a^{\frac{p}{q}}}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{y}{x-a}=\frac{p*a^{p-1}}{q*a^\frac{p(q-1)}{q}}=\frac{p}{q}*a^{p-1-\frac{p(q-1)}{q}}=\frac{p}{q}*a^{\frac{p}{q}-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

A hint: according to [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) $\exists \epsilon \in (x,a):f(x)-f(a)=f'(\epsilon)(x-a)$ where $f(x)=x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ and $f'(x)$ is also continuous, assuming $a$ is not $0$. If $a=0$, skip MVT, apply direct substitution.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer so far that actually paid attention to the OPs actual question.

Comment: Opps ... I just spotted the updated <<Please note that this question was asked by one of my students who doesn't know differentiation yet nor Lhopital nor mean value theorems>> well ... too late

Answer (score 1):

How's this?  (Depending on what you mean by "only" the rationals, this may not be what you were looking for, but it doesn't invoke the result for integers.)

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{a^n}{a^n}\cdot\frac{x^n-a^n}{\ln(x^n)-\ln(a^n)}\cdot\frac{\ln(x^n)-\ln(a^n)}{x-a}\cdot\frac{a}{a}\right) = \lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{a^n(x^n-a^n)}{a^n\ln\left(\frac{x^n}{a^n}\right)}\cdot\frac{an\ln\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{a(x-a)}\right) = \lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{a^n}{\ln\left(\frac{x^n-a^n}{a^n}+1\right)^\frac{a^n}{x^n-a^n}}\cdot\frac{n\ln\left(\frac{x-a}{a}+1\right)^\frac{a}{x-a}}{a}\right) = \frac{a^n}{\ln e}\cdot\frac{n\ln e}{a} = n\cdot a^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}\;$ is the `rate of variation`  at $x=a$ of the function $x^n$, hence the limit is, *by definition*, the derivative  of $x^n$ at $x=a$, i.e.
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}.$$

Comment: This is somewhat circular: the derivative is defined to be the result of the limit, so in order to know what the derivative of $x^n$ is at $x=a$, you need to know what the limit is!

Comment: @Clive Newstead Oh! I see. I misunderstood what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the inequalities and squeeze theorem, but proving the desired inequalities is not so easy. I have already provided details of this approach in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782225/72031) and I advise you to have a look. However you will see that proving the desired inequalities starts with the integers and then from it we deduce the inequalities for the rational numbers.

You have to understand that the idea of rationals cannot be had without the idea of integers (you may perhaps use some crafty definition which avoids the term integers like "smallest field of characteristic $0$" but you can not escape the fact that the field of rationals is the field of quotients of integers).