# How to prove the following in general: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}$?

Tags: limits

To prove

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}$$

The proof is easy when we take $n$ as positive integer and $a$ any positive real number.

In my book it is given that the result is true even when $n$ is any rational number and $a$ any positive real number. But the proof is not given.

Please provide some hint to construct the proof for general case.

Comment: You may look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782225/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Your answer to the previous one is really more than elegant  ! +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x^{p/q}-a^{p/q}}{x-a} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{\left(x^{p/q}-a^{p/q}\right)\left(x^{(q-1)p/q} + x^{(q-2)p/q}a^{p/q} + \cdots + x^{p/q}a^{(q-2)p/q} + a^{(q-1)p/q}\right)}{\left(x-a\right) \left(x^{(q-1)p/q} + x^{(q-2)p/q}a^{p/q} + \cdots + x^{p/q}a^{(q-2)p/q} + a^{(q-1)p/q}\right)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x^p - a^p}{\left(x-a\right) \left(x^{(q-1)p/q} + x^{(q-2)p/q}a^{p/q} + \cdots + x^{p/q}a^{(q-2)p/q} + a^{(q-1)p/q}\right)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{\left(x-a\right) \left(x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}a + \cdots + xa^{p-2} + a^{p-1}\right)}{\left(x-a\right) \left(x^{(q-1)p/q} + x^{(q-2)p/q}a^{p/q} + \cdots + x^{p/q}a^{(q-2)p/q} + a^{(q-1)p/q}\right)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}a + \cdots + xa^{p-2} + a^{p-1}}{x^{(q-1)p/q} + x^{(q-2)p/q}a^{p/q} + \cdots + x^{p/q}a^{(q-2)p/q} + a^{(q-1)p/q}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{a^{p-1} + a^{p-2}a + \cdots + aa^{p-2} + a^{p-1}}{a^{(q-1)p/q} + a^{(q-2)p/q}a^{p/q} + \cdots + a^{p/q}a^{(q-2)p/q} + a^{(q-1)p/q}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{pa^{p-1}}{qa^{(q-1)p/q}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac p q a^{(p-1)-(q-1)p/q} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac p q a^{p-1-p+p/q} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac p q a^{p/q-1} \\
&=& \displaystyle n a^{n-1} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Whether you realized or not the proof you gave assumes the continuity of function $x^{1/q}$ at $a$ and this is not as trivial as proving continuity for $x^{q} $. It requires essentially the theorem concerning continuity of inverse functions.

Answer (score 9):

*One possible way to show it.*

Let $x=y+a$ to change the problem to  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=\lim_{y\rightarrow o} \frac{(y+a)^n-a^n}{y}$$ Now, use the generalized binomial theorem or Taylor series around $y=0$ $$(y+a)^n=a^n+n y a^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}n (n-1)  y^2 a^{n-2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ which makes $$A=\frac{(y+a)^n-a^n}{y}=\frac{a^n+n y a^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}n (n-1)  y^2 a^{n-2}+O\left(y^3\right) -a^n}{y}$$ that is to say $$A=n a^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}n (n-1)  y a^{n-2}+O\left(y^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Comment: Most proofs of generalized binomial theorem rely on the limit in question here. One can however prove the general binomial theorem without this limit also but with somewhat more effort.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. I hope that you will not be surprised if I say that I fully agree with you. This is why I started writing *One possible way to show it*. With this kind of problems, I always have the feeling that we are inside an infinite loop. Cheers and thahnks for your comment.

Comment: Believe it or not, but I somehow missed your opening sentence. Pending +1 delivered!

Answer (score 5):

If $n=p/q$, do the substitution $x=y^q$ (which is surely possible for $x>0$, with $y>0$; do the other cases separately) and $a=b^q$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{y\to b}\frac{y^p-b^p}{y^q-b^q}=
\lim_{y\to b}\frac{y^p-b^p}{y-b}\frac{y-b}{y^q-b^q}=
\frac{pa^{p-1}}{qa^{q-1}}
$$
the last equality for the integer case.

---

I find such computations a waste of time. There's a much faster way to prove the result.

For the function $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ (where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary real number) defined for $x>0$ we have $f(x)=\exp(\alpha\log x)$ and the chain rule says
$$
f'(x)=\exp(\alpha\log x)\frac{\alpha}{x}=x^{\alpha}\frac{\alpha}{x}=
\alpha x^{\alpha-1}
$$
For rational $\alpha$ this might be defined also for $x\le0$, but it's easy to do the case with the help of symmetries.

Comment: This particular theorem seems like one you'd be proving *before* defining derivatives, or at any rate before having the derivatives of exp and log available for use.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I've nothing against trying one's hand with $n=2/3$ or $n=3/2$. The way I showed reduces the problem to the integers and could be used for explaining substitutions in limits (with proper handling of the various situations), but risks to give a wrong idea about the nature of mathematics. See the most voted answer to get what I mean.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with your last comment. +1 for answer as well as comment.

Answer (score 0):

As it is( 0/0) form apply  L  lopital  rule
Differentiate you get

=a^n-1÷(a-1)
 as limit tends to a ( 0/0) form 
So differentiate with respect to a

=na^(n-1)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please use [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help you typeset Math nicely on this site, to make your answer more readable