# Inequality of cauchy

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I found the following inequality in a book, dubbed "Cauchy's inequality for subunitary exponent":

$$ sb^{s-1}(b-a) < b^s - a^s < sa^{s-1}(b-a)\text{ } (0<a<b, s \in (0,1))$$

I tried proving it, but i didn't have much luck. I defined the function 
$$f(s) = b^s - a^s -  sb^{s-1}(b-a).$$
in order to prove the first inequality.
Obviously $f(0) = 0$, and so if I could prove that $f'(s) > 0$ when $s \in (0,1)$, I would be done. However, I didn't have much luck proving this inequality either.

How could one prove this?

Comment: Hardy proves it using basic algebra in his classic *A Course of Pure Mathematics*. The same proof is given in this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782225/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Using mean value theorem
$$ \frac{b^s-a^s}{b-a} = sc^{s-1} $$
for $c\in(a, b)$.

Can you continue?