# Proof of a real version of a discrete inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Good evening, I was wondering how to prove easily this inequality:
\begin{equation}
py^{p-1}(x-y)\leq x^p-y^p\leq px^{p-1}(x-y)
\end{equation}
for all $x,y\geq0$ and $p\in[1,+\infty)$.

I tried to study both the functions $\frac{x^p-y^p}{y^{p-1}(x-y)}$ and $\frac{x^p-y^p}{x^{p-1}(x-y)}$, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: And another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2956202 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24py%5E%7Bp-1%7D(x-y)%5Cleq%20x%5Ep-y%5Ep%5Cleq%20px%5E%7Bp-1%7D(x-y)%24)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x \geq  y$ this follows immediately from MVT applied to the function $f(x)=x^{p}$  since $py^{p-1} \leq pt^{p-1} \leq px^{p-1}$ when $t \in [x,y]$. For $x<y$ just switch $x$ and $y$ and multiply the inequalities by $-1$.

Comment: Thank you, very much!

Answer (score 0):

A purely algebraic proof when $p$ is an integer, using high school algebra: we have the factorisation
$$x^p-y^p=(x-y)(\underbrace{x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}y+\dots+xy^{p-2}+y^{p-1})}_{p\,\text{ terms}},$$
so that the second factor is $\le px^{p-1}\:$  and $\ge py^{p-1}\:$ if $\:0\le y\le x$. Multiplying by $x-y$ which is $\ge 0$ yields the result in this case.

If $0\le x\le y$, just permute the bounds for the second factor, and take into account that multiplying by $x-y\le 0$ yields again the inequalities.

Comment: $p$ is  not given to be an integer.

Comment: But the factorization holds also for $p\geq1$ not necessarily integer, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you, very much!

Comment: @UnusualMathem: I think it would be more complex for a non-integer exponent – the number of terms in the second factor, for instance, has to be a natural number. Maybe  we might obtain it with $\lfloor p\rfloor$, but I don't think it's worth the hassle.