# A simple proof of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n}=0$ for students of a high school

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, soft-question, education, limits-without-lhopital

The question refers to the mathematics course for the students of a fifth scientific high school, whereas the order of the arguments of the textbook is almost identical to what I treated when I was studying at the university.

Here a graph of the arguments:

$$\color{brown}{\text{sequences}}\to \color{red}{\text{topology in }\Bbb R \text{ and }\Bbb R^2}\to\color{gray}{\text{limits of functions}}\to$$
$$\color{magenta}{\text{continuity}}\to \color{cyan}{\text{discontinuity}}\to\color{teal}{\text{derivates}}\to$$
$$\color{blue}{\text{max and min}}\to \color{green}{\text{study of functions in reals}}\to\color{orange}{\text{indefinite and definite integration}}$$
etc.

We suppose that we have this limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n}$$

it goes to $0$, because for $n\in \Bbb N$ large, I have $0\leq \ln n<n$, i.e. the natural logarithm sequence of $n$, i.e. $\{\ln n\}$ is much slower than the sequence $\{n\}$. i.e. we say that the sequence $\{n\}$ is predominant to $\{\ln n\}$; hence it is "*similar*" to have

$$\bbox[yellow,5px]{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\text{constant}}{n}=0}$$

> Is there an alternative clear proof that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n}=0, \quad ?$$

Is there also something like:
$$\bbox[orange,5px]{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(f(n))}{g(n)}}$$

> Is there any known limit if $f(n)$  and $g(n)$ are two polynomials with $$\deg(f(n))\gtreqless\deg(g(n))\quad ?$$

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128335/discussion-on-question-by-sebastiano-a-simple-proof-of-lim-n-to-infty-frac).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard proof I know for high-school consists in proving first (with derivatives) that $\;\ln x < \sqrt x\;$ for all $x>0$.

Then one deduces that, for all $n\ge 1$,
$$0\le\frac{\ln n}n<\frac{\sqrt n}n=\frac1{\sqrt n},$$
and observes the latter expression tends  to $0$.

For the last question, as far as I know, requires asymptotic analysis, namely finding an asymptotic equivalent for $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ (their leading monomials), but I don't think this is in the high school cursus in any country.

*Edit*: Actually, one may circumvent the use of asymptotic analysis,at the cost of a slightly longer proof. Let:
\begin{align}f(n)&= an^k + \sum_{i=k-1}^0 a_ix^i,&
g(n)&= cn^l +  \sum_{i=l-1}^0 c_ix^i.
\end{align}
Then we may write
$\ln (f(n)=\ln(an^k)+\sum_{i=k-1}^0\frac{a_i}{a x^{k-i}}$, so that
$$\frac{\ln\bigl(f(n)\bigr)}{g(n)}=\frac{\ln\ a}{g(n)}+\frac{k\ln(n)}{g(n)},$$
and it is a simple routine to show that each of these fractions  tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Why do you need asymptotic equivalent of $f$ and $g$? $\log f(n)$ is bounded by constant multiple of $(n+1)\log x$ (there is a one line proof), so the limit is zero for any degree of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Most of the time,  I use equivalents because they yield the shortest proofs.

Comment: Our answer looks like I saw it after refreshing the page.  Maybe I can consider deleting it.

Comment: I don't think so. You use substitution + L'Hospital, which is another approach.

Comment: @lonestudent Ahhahahah. Don't worry for this :-) Now I adopt my method :-)

Answer (score 4):

On the request of OP, I am writing an answer based on my comments to the question. The presentation is designed to be at an elementary level and avoids derivatives / integrals.

---

Natural logarithm is characterized by two key properties:

- $\log (xy) =\log x+\log y, \, \forall x, y>0$
- $\log x\leq x - 1,\,\forall x>0$

in the sense that *any function $f:\mathbb {R} ^+\to\mathbb {R} $ which satisfies $f(xy) =f(x) +f(y), f(x) \leq x - 1$ is the natural logarithm*.

We use the above properties to prove the desired limit in question. Let $n$ be a positive integer and then we have $$0\leq \log \sqrt{n} \leq \sqrt {n} - 1<\sqrt{n}$$ or $$0\leq \log n<2\sqrt{n}$$ or $$0\leq\frac{\log n} {n} <\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$$ Applying squeeze theorem we can see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n} {n} =0$$

---

Next let us use a definition of logarithm which establishes the fundamental properties described at the start of the answer. The simplest approach is using $\log x =\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$ but it needs a reasonable development of integral calculus (in particular one needs to show that the integral exists).

Instead we assume the convergence of bounded and monotone sequences and define $$\log x=\lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{1/n}-1),\,\forall x>0\tag{1}$$ By definition we have $\log 1=0$. We show that the limit exists not just for $x=1$ (trivial case), but also for all other positive values of $x$.

We make use the following key inequalities $$\frac{a^r-1}{r}>\frac{a^s-1}{s},\frac{1-b^r}{r}<\frac{1-b^s}{s}\tag{2}$$ where $a, b$ are real numbers with $0<b<1<a$ and $r, s$ are rational numbers with $r>s>0$. The inequalities are established using algebraic manipulation [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782225/72031).

Let $f(x, n) =n(x^{1/n}-1)$. Putting $r=1/n,s=1/(n+1)$ and $a=x$ if $x>1$ and $b=x$ if $0<x<1$ in $(2)$ we see that $f(x, n) $ is a decreasing sequence of $n$. For $x>1$ we can note that $f(x, n) >0$ and hence $f(x, n) $ tends to a limit as $n\to\infty $.

For $0<x<1$ we need a bit more work. Let $y=1/x>1$ and then $$f(x, n) =n((1/y)^{1/n} - 1)=-\frac{n(y^{1/n}-1)}{y^{1/n}}=-\frac{f(y, n)} {y^{1/n}} \tag{3}$$ Now $f(y, n) $ tends to a limit and $y^{1/n}\to 1$ so that $f(x, n) $ tends to a limit.

It is now established that the limit in $(1)$ exists for all positive real numbers $x$ and hence the logarithm function is well defined with domain $\mathbb {R} ^+$.

Next we have for positive real numbers $x, y$
\begin{align}
\log (xy) &=\lim_{n\to \infty} n((xy) ^{1/n}-1)\notag\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} n(x^{1/n}y^{1/n}-y^{1/n}+y^{1/n}-1)\notag\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} y^{1/n}\cdot n(x^{1/n}-1)+n(y^{1/n}-1)\notag\\
&=1\cdot\log x+\log y\notag\\
&=\log x +\log y\notag
\end{align}
Putting $y=1/x$ in above relation we get $$\log x+\log (1/x)=\log 1=0$$ and hence $$\log(1/x)=-\log x\tag{4}$$ and further $$\log(x/y) =\log x+\log(1/y)=\log x - \log y\tag{5}$$ Next we assume $x>1$ and put $r=1,s=1/n,a=x$ in $(2)$ to get $$n(x^{1/n} - 1)\leq x-1$$ and taking limits we see that $$\log x \leq x - 1$$ for all $x>1$. The inequality holds trivially for $x=1$. For $0<x<1$ we apply $(2)$ with $r=1,s=1/n,b=x$ and get the same inequality as before. Thus we have established the fundamental inequality satisfied by $\log x$ namely $$\log x\leq x-1$$ for all positive real numbers $x$.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your efforts and to give me an answer. Grazie for $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: @Sebastiano: one can go further and show that $\log x$ is differentiable with derivative $1/x$. And we can define $e$ as the unique positive number for which $\log e =1$.

Answer (score 3):

##### Comment on the Question

In the question, it is stated that since $0\le\log(n)\lt n$, we have $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}n=0
$$
By that same logic, since $0\le\frac12n\lt n$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac12n}n=0
$$
which is false.

---

##### Part 1: Pre-Calculus Approach

**Bound $\boldsymbol{\frac{\log(n)}n}$**
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n
&\ge1+\sqrt{n}\tag{1a}\\[6pt]
&\ge\sqrt{n}\tag{1b}\\[3pt]
\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2
&\ge n^{1/n}\tag{1c}\\
2\log\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)
&\ge\frac{\log(n)}n\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
$\text{(1b)}$: $1\ge0$
$\text{(1c)}$: raise to the $2/n$ power
$\text{(1d)}$: take the logarithm

Since $\frac{\log(n)}{n}\ge0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)=0$, $(1)$ and the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) imply
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}n=0\tag2
$$

---

##### Part 2: Apply to Polynomials

Let $P(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^ma_kn^k$ where $a_m\gt0$; that is, $\deg(P)=m$. Then
$$
\frac{\log(P(n))}{\log(n)}=\frac{\log\left(a_mn^m\right)}{\log(n)}+\overbrace{\ \frac1{\log(n)}\ \vphantom{\sum_{k=0}^1}}^{\substack{\text{vanishes}\\\text{as }n\to\infty}}\overbrace{\log\left(1+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{a_k}{a_m}\frac1{n^{m-k}}\right)}^{\text{vanishes as }n\to\infty}\tag3
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(P(n))}{\log(n)}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(a_mn^m\right)}{\log(n)}\tag{4a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(a_m)}{\log(n)}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{m\log(n)}{\log(n)}\tag{4b}\\[6pt]
&=0+m\tag{4c}\\[12pt]
&=\deg(P)\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, if $\deg(Q)\ge1$, regardless of $\deg(P)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(P(n))}{Q(n)}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(P(n))}{\log(n)}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{Q(n)}\tag{5a}\\
&=\deg(P)\cdot0\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{Q(n)}\tag{5b}\\[3pt]
&=0\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: limit of a product is the product of the limits
$\text{(5b)}$: apply $(2)$ and $(4)$
$\text{(5c)}$: if $\deg(Q)=1$, the limit is the reciprocal of the lead coefficient of $Q$
$\phantom{\text{(5c):}}$ if $\deg(Q)\gt1$, the limit is $0$

Comment: For the first part of your answer you are absolutely right and I had not thought about it enough. If I use the series, I will surely be sentenced to hang at school :-). This response is also beautiful. But there are many well done and I don't know which one to choose for the green tick. Generally when I do not put the green tick for me they are all beautiful. I thank you for your patience. My greetings.

Comment: When I was in high school, calculus was only offered for students who had finished the usual high school math curriculum and were willing to travel to the junior college to take it. Therefore, when I think of high school math, I think of pre-calculus. Evidently, calculus is now offered in many high schools, so this answer might not be the simplest for your class.

Comment: I liked it a lot. I added an image that is understandable even if written in Italian: starting in the 70's math questions were based on reasoning. Now, in 2021, in order to raise the level of the students' grades, all we have to do is present a rectangle and tell them to color it as they like: in this way we give them a 10/10.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $\ln n<n$ is not sufficient to conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n}=0$.

For instance, $n/2<n$ for every positive integer $n$, but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n/2}{n}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

How to prove that limit depends on how you define the logarithm and the exponential. For instance, if you define
$$
\ln x=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt
$$
you can observe that, for $0<x<1$
$$
-\ln x=\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t}\,dt=\int_x^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{t}\,dt+\int_{\sqrt{x}}^1\frac{1}{t}\,dt\le(\sqrt{x}-x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+(1-\sqrt{x})=2-2\sqrt{x}
$$
and therefore
$$
0\le-x\ln x\le 2x(1-\sqrt{x})
$$
so squeezing implies that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x\ln x=0
$$
(limit for $x\to0^+$, if you prefer). Therefore, with $y=1/x$,
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1}{y}\ln(1/y)=\lim_{y\to\infty}-\frac{\ln y}{y}=0
$$
and therefore also
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n}=0
$$
Other definitions require different proofs.

Generalizing, we can say that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n^k)}{n}=0
$$
If now $f$ is a polynomials of degrees $k>0$, we can write
$$
f(n)=a_kn^k+a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\dots+a_1n+a_0
=a_kn^k\Bigl(1+\frac{a_{k-1}}{a_kn}+\dots+\frac{a_1}{a_kn^{k-1}}+\frac{a_0}{a_kn^k}\Bigr)
$$
and, in order that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(f(n))}{n}
$$
makes sense, we need that $a_k>0$. Moreover, the fact that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(1+\frac{a_{k-1}}{a_kn}+\dots+\frac{a_1}{a_kn^{k-1}}+\frac{a_0}{a_kn^k}\Bigr)=1
$$
tells you that for $n$ greater than a suitable $\bar{n}$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}<1+\frac{a_{k-1}}{a_kn}+\dots+\frac{a_1}{a_kn^{k-1}}+\frac{a_0}{a_kn^k}<2
$$
Therefore, for $n>\bar{n}$,
$$
\frac{1}{2}a_kn^k<f(n)<2a_kn^k
$$
and now you can squeeze and conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(f(n))}{n}=0
$$
If now $g$ is another polynomial of positive degree, you can write
$$
\frac{\ln(f(n))}{g(n)}=\frac{\ln(f(n))}{n}\frac{n}{g(n)}
$$
and the limit is obviously zero.

Comment: A beautiful and very clear answer. I should always start from the limits of functions and always use the integrals :-( when you prove that $\ln x=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt$.

Answer (score 2):

For me,
the easiest proof uses
$\ln(x)
=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}
$
for $x \ge 1$.

Then,
for $x > 0$ and $0 < c < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+x)
&=\int_1^{1+x} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\int_0^{x} \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&\lt\int_0^{x} \dfrac{dt}{(1+t)^c}
\qquad\text{since }(1+t)^c < 1+t\\
&\lt\dfrac{(1+t)^{1-c}}{1-c}\big|_0^{x}\\
&=\dfrac{(1+x)^{1-c}-1}{1-c}\\
&<\dfrac{(1+x)^{1-c}}{1-c}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}
&<\dfrac{(1+x)^{-c}}{1-c}\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{ as } x \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

You can use this
to show that

$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^d} \to 0$
for $0 < d < 1$
as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Although you used integrals and unfortunately I can not adopt them when I start the sequences I appreciate so much your effort that I positively vote. +1 and upvoted also others q/a.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the fine answers already given we can also proceed as follows.

We can prove, more generally, that for $x \in \mathbb R$ we have $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x}=0$.

Notably by $x=e^y$ with $y \to \infty$

> $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x}=0 \iff \lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{e^y}{y}=\infty$$

and the the latter can be proved:

- at a first stage by induction for $n\in\mathbb N$ showing that eventually $e^n\ge n^2$ and using squeeze theorem;
- then extending the result to reals using that $\forall y\in
     \mathbb R \quad \exists n\in\mathbb N \quad y \in[n,n+1)$ such that
  $y\ge n$ and therefore using squeeze theorem:

$$\frac{e^y}{y}\ge \frac{e^n}{n} \to \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

First prove that is mononotone decreasing.

By calculus $\ln (1 + x) < x, x>0$
so

$$
\ln(n+1)=\ln n+\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)<\ln n+\frac1n.
$$

$$ n  \ln(n+1) < n \ln( n) +1 < (n+1) \ln n$$

$$ \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1}    < \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$

By definition of limit, now, you can just show that $\frac{\ln( n)}{n}$ can be in an arbitrarly small neighbourhood of $0$.

Given $K > 0$ taking $n>e^K$ we get

$$ \frac{\ln (n)}{n} < \frac{\ln (e^K)}{e^K} = \frac{K}{e^K} < K$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribute.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then the derivative of $\ln f(x)$ is $f'(x)/f(x)$ which is a rational expression with the degree of the numerator one less than the degree of the denominator.  Then by L'Hospital's Rule we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)g'(x)}.$$

The last is a rational expression with numerator degree smaller than denominator degree.  So the limit is zero.  (Assuming the degree of $g(x)$ is at least $1$.)

Comment: Hi B.Goddard. Since this question is tagged "limits-without-lhopital", I don't think that this kind of solution is what Sebastiano was looking for.

Comment: @Joe  He asked two questions.  The second question asks for the existence of a result.  I gave it.  Punkt.

Comment: @Joe Don't worry for this. Surely he hasn't seen the tag and I really appreciated his effort. However, for me it is always an opportunity to know and learn.