# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{2x+1}\right)^{\frac1x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How do you evaluate the following limit?
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{2x+1}\right)^{\frac1x}
$$

I tried to make it approach the shape of the euler limit

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)^{f(x)}
$$
I added and subtracted 1, so that we get "1 + a function", I inverted this function, making 1 / (1 / f (x)). then to the exponent I multiplied and divided by the function, in order to obtain a limit like that of euler, raised to another function
but I realized that it was not the solution, because f (x) did not go to infinity when x went to infinity.

Then I gave up and asked here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, Pasqualone. I'm afraid to say that I downvoted this question because it does meet the standards of the site, as set out in [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You should show your effort and work on that.

Comment: To improve your question, I would suggest that you (1) add your own attempts if possible, (2) tell us which textbook this question came from, and (3) briefly tell us your mathematical background—what is your level of education, and what course are you studying?

Comment: i tried the exercise several times and i couldn't, i found the exercise on youmath, i just asked for help

Comment: @Pasqualone That's fine but to obtain some help it is necessary that you show your work and effort on that by editing and completing the question. What have you tried exactly?

Comment: @Pasqualone: Okay, so can you edit your question to include your attempts? It would also be wise to indicate where you got this question from. And finally, can you tell us about your mathematical background, so that the answers are pitched at the right level?

Comment: As to your assessing your level - are you aware of the limit definition of $e$? L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not mistaken that the exercise wanted me to solve it without the hospital

Comment: @Pasqualone It is indeed solveable without l'Hospital but you need to edit your question in order to reopen it and obtain some indication or help for the solution.

Comment: Did you see *asymptotic equivalence*?

Comment: no, I added and subtracted 1, so that we get "1 + a function", I inverted this function, making 1 / (1 / f (x)). then to the exponent I multiplied and divided by the function, in order to obtain a limit like that of euler, raised to another function
but I realized that it was not the solution, because f (x) did not go to infinity when x went to infinity

Comment: @Pasqualone Have you tried with the exponential trick $f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\log(f(x))}$?

Comment: @Pasqualone Well done for the editing! Can you see the difference and how much it is important give the necessary context to the question?

Comment: @Pasqualone: Well done for improving your question! We've reopened your post, and I have removed my downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use exponential trick in this way

$$\left(\frac{x^2}{2x+1}\right)^{1/x}=e^{\frac{\log\left(\frac{x^2}{2x+1}\right)}x}\to e^0=1$$

indeed by standard limit $\frac{\log x}x \to 0$ we have

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{x^2}{2x+1}\right)}x=\frac{\log\left(\frac{x^2}{2x+1}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{2x+1}}\frac{x}{2x+1}\to 0\cdot \frac 12 =0$$

See also the related

[A simple proof of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n}=0$ for students of a high school](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4213581/505767)

Comment: The link it is my question: then to something it has been useful .

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes indeed, it is very useful! Thanks