# How to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{a^{2x}-2}{x^x}=-1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried like this:

Let $y=a^{2x}-2\Rightarrow a^{2x}=y+2\Rightarrow 2x\ln a=\ln\left(y+2\right)\Rightarrow x=\dfrac{\ln\left(y+2\right)}{2\ln a}$

Also if $x\longrightarrow0,$ then $y\longrightarrow a^{2(0)}-2=-1.$

But we I put each and every this assumption in the given expression, then I get hanged due to $x^x.$ How to use algebra or any other easy procedure to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{a^{2x}-2}{x^x}=-1$.

Comment: For your problem-solving toolbox: whenever you see an expression of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$, you should always rewrite it as $e^{g(x)\ln (f(x))}$.

Answer (score 5):

We don't need to make any manipulation, by limit quotient theorem we have that for $a\neq 0$ and $x>0$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{a^{2x}-2}{x^x}=\dfrac{\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(a^{2x}-2\right)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^x}=\frac{-1}1=-1$$

indeed

- $a^{2x}-2\to1-2=-1$
- $x^x=e^{x \log x} \to e^0=1$

for the latter refer also to

- [A simple proof of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n}=0$ for students of a high school](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4213581/505767)

Answer (score 4):

I think it is enough to consider $x>0$ due to quantities like $x^x$. In this case $x\ln x \to 0$ as $x\to 0+$. The result follows due to $x^x = \exp (x\ln x)$.

Comment: At this point, I am actually out of my depth.  Therefore, I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 FWIW, I think the article is fine. Rather, I think you are mis-interpreting its content.

Answer (score 1):

The secret here is to express $\dfrac{a^{2x}-2}{x^x}$ a function of the $\dfrac{e^{y}-1}{y}$, with $y=(2\cdot \ln a)\cdot x$, and function the $x\cdot \ln x$.

Note that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{a^{2x}-2}{x^x}
=&
\dfrac{a^{2x}-1}{x^x}-\dfrac{1}{x^x}
\\
=&
\dfrac{(e^{\ln a})^{2x}-1}{2x}\cdot\dfrac{2x}{x^x}-\dfrac{1}{x^x}
\\
=&
\dfrac{e^{2(\ln a)x}-1}{2x}
\cdot 
\dfrac{2x}{e^{x\ln x}}
-
\dfrac{1}{e^{x\ln x}}
\\
=&
\left(
(\ln a)
\cdot\dfrac{e^{2(\ln a)x}-1}{2(\ln a)x}
\cdot 
2x
-
1
\right)
\cdot 
\frac{1}{e^{x\cdot \ln x}}
\\
\end{align}
We have

- $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^{2(\ln a)x}-1}{2(\ln a)x}=1$ implies
  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}(\ln a)
  \cdot\dfrac{e^{2(\ln a)x}-1}{2(\ln a)x}
  \cdot 
  2x=0$
- $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot \ln x=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln x}{\left(\dfrac{1}{x} \right)}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{D(\ln x)}{D\left(\dfrac{1}{x} \right)}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)}{\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}-x=0$
  implies $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{e^{x\cdot \ln x}}=\dfrac{1}{e^{(\; \lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot \ln x)}}=\dfrac{1}{e^{0}}=1$

Answer (score 0):

Given

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{a^{2x}-2}{x^x}=-1
\implies
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{a^{2x}-2}{x^x} +1 =0
\end{equation}
You say,"then I get hanged due to  $^$.." but $0^0=1$ and we can even eliminate the denominator if that isn't enough.

\begin{align*}
(\large{x}^x)
\small{\bigg(\dfrac{a^{2x}-2}{x^x}} + 1\bigg)=0
\implies 
\space&a^{2 x} + x^x - 2=0\\ \\
 a^{2 x} + x^x - 2=0
\implies& a^{2 x} + x^x = 2\\
\end{align*}
We can see by inspection that the derived limit below is valid.
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x \to 0}a^{2 x} + x^x\space  =1+1=2\\
\text{ therefore}&\\
&\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{a^{2x}\space -2}{x^x}=-1 
\end{align*}

Another approach is using simple substitution , permitted here because there is no possible division by zero.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{a^{2x}\space -2}{x^x}
=\frac{2^0-2}{0^0}=\frac{-1}{1}=-1$$