# Prove Differentiable from First Principles.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm struggling to prove from first principles that the function $f(x)$ is differentiable.

Definition of differentiable:

> Let $S$ be an open interval and let $f : S \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a function. Let $x_0 \in S$. we say that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if the limit $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac {f(x)-f(x_0)} {x-x_0}$$ exists. If this is the case, then the limit i denoted by $f'(x_0)$ and called the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$.

Prove from first principles that the function $g : \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & 0 \\
x^3\sin\left(x^{-4}\right), & x \ne 0
\end{cases}
$$ is differentiable.

Comment: If this is from a textbook, I'm curious as to which one. If this was assigned in a class, it seems rather pointless and sadistic to me since I don't see the skills being developed of any use. Separately obtaining the derivative of $x^3$ and maybe $1/x^4$ by first principles are reasonable, as well as $\sin x$ (for which you'll have to make use of a certain well known limit), but what you have seems going overboard. **(continued)**

Comment: And for what it's worth, I say this despite my answer to [Differentiation using first principles with rational powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382796/differentiation-using-first-principles-with-rational-powers). (At least what I did there illustrates several sometimes useful methods. I don't see this happening in your case.) I wonder if what you **really want** is to show the function is differentiable at $x=0$ from first principles?