# differentiation using formal definition i.e. $(x+h)$

Tags: derivatives

Using first principles, differentiate $$f(x)=(x)^{\frac{3}{4}} $$

So$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^{\frac{3}{4}} -(x)^{\frac{3}{4}}}{h} $$

I cant seem to solve this question. I'm supposed to get the 
 output $\frac{3}{4}x^{-\frac{1}{4}} $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: multiply the numerator and denominator by $((x+h)^{\frac{3}{4}}+x^{\frac{3}{4}})((x+h)^{\frac{3}{2}}+x^{\frac{3}{2}})$. Don't foil out the denominator and see what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differentiation using first principles with rational powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382796/differentiation-using-first-principles-with-rational-powers)

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving this problem is to apply the binomial series to $(x+h)^\frac{3}{4}$.
$$(x+h)^\frac{3}{4}=x^\frac{3}{4}(1+\frac{h}{x})^\frac{3}{4}=x^\frac{3}{4}(1+\frac{3h}{4x}+...).$$
Then $(x+h)^\frac{3}{4}-x^\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3h}{4}x^{-\frac{1}{4}}+...$

and $\frac{(x+h)^\frac{3}{4}-x^\frac{3}{4}}{h}=\frac{3}{4}x^{-\frac{1}{4}}.$

Comment: When you expand $ (1+\frac{h}{x})^{\frac{3}{4}} $, it seems like you are using a Taylor Series expansion, which I'm not sure counts as first principles. I feel like there should be a way just using algebraic manipulations in the difference quotient to arrive at the desired derivative.

Comment: For a school lesson I think that first principles simply implies letting $h$ tend to zero using the techniques they already know. I don't think it would help this student to do any other method

Comment: Binomial expansions with non integer powers are difficult to understand or motivate without calculus. I agree with @poopstraw, there is a standard algebraic manipulation using conjugates (in this case, using difference of squares twice) i.e. multiply the numerator and denominator by $((x+h)^{\frac{3}{4}}+x^{\frac{3}{4}})((x+h)^{\frac{3}{2}}+x^{\frac{3}{2}})$

Comment: The binomial series is a standard school topic which is expected in questions like this one.

Comment: @S.Dolan I disagree, this is not a standard high school topic at all. In order to prove the formula works for non integer powers, one needs calculus, so it would be very strange to be using it before having that tool. Not to mention, that binomial series is only valid for $|x|<1$.